# Why do np.random.randn and np.zeros take different kinds of argument?

Tags: python, numpy

Initializing an array with random numbers can be achieved like this:

```py
arr_1 = np.random.randn(3,5)
```

Initializing with all entries equal to `0` is done like so:

```py
arr_2 = np.zeros((3,5))
```

To specify the desired shape, `np.random.randn` takes integers as arguments, whereas `np.zeros` expects a tuple of integers (which is then equal to the shape of the returned array). When working with these functions, I often confuse one with the other.
Why do these functions take different kinds of arguments for specifying the shape?

First, I thought that functions from `np.random` (like `randn`) do this way and functions directly from `np` (like `zeros` or `ones`) do that way. This seems however not to be the case: `np.random.randint` takes, among other parameters, the shape as a tuple, unlike `np.random.randn`.

Comment: The respective function docs should clearly show the correct arguments.  Looking for patterns and consistencies is nice, but not a substitute.  To add to your confusion, `np.reshape` takes a shape tuple, but the `reshape` method accepts either the tuple or 'unpacked' values.  In your own code you can write a function that accepts `args` or one that accepts `*args` (and this could further modified to work with one tuple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randn.html#numpy.random.randn):

> This is a convenience function for users porting code from Matlab, and wraps [`standard_normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.standard_normal.html#numpy.random.standard_normal). That function takes a tuple to specify the size of the output, which is consistent with other NumPy functions like [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html#numpy.zeros) and [`numpy.ones`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html#numpy.ones).

Comment: So np.random.randn(a,b) is equivalent with np.random.standard_normal((a,b))? Is it thus preferred to use standard_normal over randn?

Comment: Yes @NerdOnTour - You should use `standard_normal`